# win api - how to implement a separate events procedure for tree view

Tags: c, winapi, subclassing

I have created a main window (CreateWindowEx) with events procedure set using  WNDCLASSEXW:

`wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;`.

Next I have created a child window which is used as tree view:

```
    HWND hwndTRV = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        WC_TREEVIEW,
        TEXT("Tree View"),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | TVS_HASLINES | TVS_EDITLABELS,
        0,
        0,
        rcClient.right,
        rcClient.bottom,
        hwndParent,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);
```

I would like to handle a tree view specific events in the separate function. I use the following code:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hwndTRV, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)TRVProc);
```

How should I implement the TRVProc ? Here is an example code, TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT and TVN_ENDLABELEDIT events are not visible in TRVProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK TRVProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_NOTIFY:
        {
            LPNMHDR l = (LPNMHDR)lParam;

            switch (l->code)
            {
                case TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT:
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                case TVN_ENDLABELEDIT:
                {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return CallWindowProc(WndProc, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

A message loop looks this way:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
{
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation for these notification messages. The first thing it says is that they are sent to the tree view's parent control. So you need to handle those notifications in the parent window's window procedure.

Comment: And also, in the few rare cases where you ever do need to subclass the TreeView itself to handle internal messages, you should use `SetWindowSubclass()` instead of `SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_WNDPROC)`

Comment: If you don't subclass can you receive `TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT` in the `WndProc` for main window? If you can, show a mini, complete and reproducible sample so I can try to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Hi Irbis, feel free let me know if there is still any problem about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a separate events procedure for tree view is possible based on the document:

> Calling `SetWindowLongPtr` with the `GWLP_WNDPROC` index creates a
>   **subclass** of the window class used to create the window. An application
>   must pass any messages not processed by the new window procedure to
>   the previous window procedure by calling `CallWindowProc`. This allows
>   the application to create **a chain of window procedures**.

You want to replace the default window procedure of **parent window** (`hwndParent`) instead of tree view window (`hwndTRV`). So the related code line will like this:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hwndParent, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)TRVProc);
```

Additionally, to receive [`TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tvn-beginlabeledit) and [`TVN_ENDLABELEDIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tvn-endlabeledit) notification code you may have **add some items** to the tree view first. Then when you edit item's label the `TRVProc` will receive above notification code. For an example of how to add some items you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/add-tree-view-items) official document.